# How to reverse an array of arabic alphabet ?

Tags: javascript

I am having an array of an Arabic alphabet, I want to reverse the array, I am using `.reverse()` function for the reverse functionality, `.reverse` function is working fine for an array of english alphabet but it is not working for the Arabic alphabet array, can anyone help me to solve the issue, Thanks in advance

---

**My sollution**

```
const arabic_alpha = ['ا', 'ب', 'پ', 'ت', 'ث', 'ج', 'چ', 'ح', 'خ', 'د', 'ذ', 'ر', 'ز', 'ژ', 'ص', 'ض', 'ط', 'ظ', 'ع', 'غ', 'ف', 'ق', 'ک', 'گ', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'و', 'ه', 'ی'];

const rev = arabic_alpha.reverse();

rev :
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: when copying it to my console I noticed it got automatically reversed, weird, so you probably don't need to .reverse() it, even though it shows wrong for you

Comment: the method has nothing to do with the encoding (arabic, english ...) as it just reverse every thing

Comment: keep in mind, `reverse()` works in-place, so after running this code, both `arabic_alpha` and `rev` will be in reverse order when compared to the array you originally initialized with

Comment: *arabic_alpha* and *rev* reference the same array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be working, check out the `fiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/umy5ox44/3

I'm loging Your alphabet array before and after the `reverse()` function, and the logs show it's ok.

Please note, when using the `reverse()` function, You also reverse the original array. To keep it intact, try:

```
rev = arabic_alphabet.slice();
rev.reverse();
```

Also please verify You're using the right reference when displaying the result

Comment: Your "keep it intact" snippet will still reverse the original array.

Comment: @georg updated, i wrote about it a bit later, for I wanted to be sure :)